# Remove check boxes and headings from List Web Part

Tags: web-part, list

I have created list. I want to include this on another page so I use the corresponding list web part. I do not want the heading row and the individual check boxes to appear.

I have tried which works on the list view but not when the list is in a web part. The headings are still there.

[image: SharePoint 2010 Tabular View]

Is there a way that I can remove them in the web part?

Comment: Did you change the list view after you set up the list web part? If you did, then you need to update the list view of you web part. List view web parts create a copy of the list view you had selected.

Answer (score 2):

Open the web part in Designer in a split view w/ code/design views open. Click the boxes you don't want in design view and hit delete. If you want to refine the area after you delete them, select them using design view and then modify the highlighted code in code view.

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue in SP2013. The checkboxes were removed from the view in the list but would not update in the webpart displaying list items. Updating the view in the web part would remove the checkboxes but saving the page would revert it back to the original view with checkboxes.

I ended up having to remove the web part and readd it for the changes to appear.

Answer (score 1):

Exact same issue in SP2013 as user24085. I had already tried the tabular view check box and configuring the webpart to refresh the view settings. Deleting and adding the app web part back to the page resolved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I researched this issue for hours and found a simple and easy solution. In my case, I want to remove individual checkboxes and prevent double clicks on the list web part. The solution is tested over the SharePoint 2019 on-prem.

First, you need to add the **react-script-editor** web part to your page. If you do not have **react-script-editor**, please use the below link to get it.

For on-prem
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor-onprem

For SharePoint Online
https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-script-editor

Then inject the following code scripts into the script editor.

1. Prevent double click and remove individual checkboxes.

   ```
   <script 
   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"> 
   </script>

   $(document).ready(function () {
      $('.ms-DetailsRow').css({'pointer-events':'none'});

   });
   ```
2. If you want to allow clicks in any specific column or item, You can allow it using the CSS selector. As an example I want to allow mouse click on Hyperlink type columns, So I change the script like follows,

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
     $('[data-automationid=FieldRenderer-url]').css({'pointer- 
          events':'all'});
     $('.ms-DetailsRow').css({'pointer-events':'none'});

   });
   ```

**Note***
'ms-DetailsRow' is the class that I identified in the list web part row. If this solution is not working, Please check your web part row identifier and change the code according to the identifier.